# Connect desktop to wireless network via wifi repeater with ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wifi-configuration

I have a win 10 desktop with a malfunctioning wifi adapter and I am trying to connect it to my home's wifi network.

However, the router is located too far away and it is not possible to connect directly by cable.

I have an unused ASUS RT-AC51U router that I was thinking if using it as an wifi repeater, place it near the desktop and connect to it via ethernet. Is this possible with this equipment? I was browsing in the ASUS admin panel but couldn't come up with a solution, since I don't understand most of the options/configurations...

Is there a way to make this work, or is there another solution?

Thank you

Comment: Trying to use an older router as a wireless extender may or may not work depending on the equipment specifications. Other solution?  Wireless USB Adapter.  This will be simpler overall.

Answer (score 1):

The ASUS RT-AC51U router is described in its
[manual](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/D1M33tFdcMS.pdf).

The mode you're looking for is called
Bridge or WDS (Wireless Distribution System),
as described on page 53.

You will find detailed instruction in the ASUS post
[[Wireless Router] How to set up WDS](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/114612/).
Although it describes also the setting of the primary WiFi server,
you should concentrate on the part about the secondary monitor.
You will need the MAC address of the primary WiFi router.

The required steps from the article:

> 1. Connect the Secondary Router to your computer. On a web browser, key in `http://192.168.1.1` to launch the router's web interface.
>    Click *Advanced Settings > Wireless > Bridge* tab.
> 2. Set the same frequency as in the Primary Router (here is 5GHz), and select the AP Mode as Hybrid or WDS mode. Hybrid mode used to both
>    wired and wireless clients while WDS mode used to wireless clients
>    only.
> 3. Enable *Connect to APs in list*.
> 4. Select the same channel as in the Primary Router. In this example, we selected 36 as the channel for the Primary Router, so we will
>    select 36 for this field.
> 5. In the Remote AP list field, key in the MAC address of the Primary Router. In the example, we previously specified 5GHz as the frequency,
>    so we will key the 5GHz MAC address of the Secondary Router.
> 6. Click ADD mark.
> 7. Click APPLY.
> 8. Asssign a static LAN IP address for the Secondary Router such as 192.168.1.2.
> 9. Disable the DHCP server.

Comment: I believe this advice is incorrect.  WDS mode is only for speaking to other routers. per pages 50/51 of the manual you need Hybrid mode.

Comment: @davidgo: The documentation is quite unclear - I thought the same as you at first. However, the above text clearly says: "Hybrid mode used to both wired and wireless clients while WDS mode used to wireless clients only". Hybrid mode is also half the speed of WDS.

Comment: Apologies for the downvote.  I confirm it was me that downvoted you, and I confirm I have a great deal of respect for you (and checked myself before the downvote, but still got it wrong!).  On further research I also see that my understanding of WDS mode was incorrect.